# Не срабатывает условие на актинвость кнопки

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. Делаю кнопку неактивной. Необходимо заполнить все поля после чего клавиша станет активной, но условие не срабатывает. Подскажите в чем проблема.

```
   procedure TForm7.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    begin
  if (edit1.Text<>'')and (edit2.Text<>'')and (edit3.Text<>'')and (edit4.Text<>'') and
   (edit5.Text<>'') and (edit6.Text<>'') and (edit7.Text<>'') then
    Form7.Button1.Enabled:=True;
     end;

      end.
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что этот код выполняется? для всех ли edit'ов назначен этот обработчик (как я понимаю такая задача решалась)? Поставьте точку останова, проверьте для каждого из edit'ов.

Comment: сейчас проверю

Comment: спасибо, все работает, сделал для всех эдитов , заработало

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача должна решаться с помощью `TAction`